# Glassfish Deploy CommandException Error

Tags: exception, deployment, glassfish-3

I want to deploy my application to glassvish v3 with asadmin deploy command however I get an error:

```
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CommandException: remote failure: There is no installed container capable of handling this application com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared.FileArchive@1c2a1c7
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: I got the same error,please help. I'm new to Glassfish.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the problem was coming from the fact that in /domains/domain/applications there was still the application I was trying to deploy again.

Answer (score 2):

Another file access possibility I just ran into:

Service was started as root and the app undeployed/deployed. Then, as the correct limited rights user, undeploy/deploy. On deploy you'll receive this error, as the application files will still exist in he 'domains/yourdomain/applications' directory, and will be owned by root.

+1 to Keeg's comment on the awesome error messages we've all come to expect from Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the same error.In my case,I'd made a directory named **"Web-INF"**,apparently the name of the folder has to be ***(mandatory)*** in upper-case i.e. **"WEB-INF"**.
**In short,check for spelling errors.**

It solved my issue.So just wanted to share.I'm new to glassfish, so can't really tell you the exact solution.But what worked for me could be a solution for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else finds this question and the above answer doesn't match your case... Our problem was that the temporary area on the Glassfish server was full. Clearing some space let me redeploy the same application. Thank goodness for excellent error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had an ear project, where the ear package had different version number configured to maven `pom.xml` than the rest of the projects it contained. It searched sub-modules from version 1.x and the rest of the project was at 1.y version. I updated every pom to same version and that made the trick.